# AJAX: Two requests at the same time

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet.

I am new to `AJAX` and `JQuery`.

I am sending two request from my `jsp` page to `servlet` using following **code:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var $ul = $(SALUTATION);
        $.get('MyServletName?action=cmbSALUTATION', function(responseJson) 
        {
            $.each(responseJson, function(index, item)
            { 
                $('<option>').text(item).appendTo($ul);
            });
        });
        setValSALUTATION(); 
});

function setValSALUTATION()
{
        $.get('ProfileContactsMain?action=cmbSALUTATIONValue', function(responseJson)
        {
            $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) 
            {
            $("#SALUTATION").val(item);
            });
        });
}
```

First one fills the values in html `combobox` and second one sets the value in `combobox` for that record from the database. Combobox is filled everytime, but the value for that particular record is not set everytime, sometimes `setValSALUTATION()` is executed before the data is loaded in the combobox.

so is anything wrong in my code? or is there any better way to do this....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Reason for downvoting will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            var $ul = $(SALUTATION);
            $.get('MyServletName?action=cmbSALUTATION', function(responseJson) 
            {
                $.each(responseJson, function(index, item)
                { 
                    $('<option value=' + item +'>').text(item).appendTo($ul);
                });
 setValSALUTATION(); 
            });

    });

function setValSALUTATION()
{
        $.get('ProfileContactsMain?action=cmbSALUTATIONValue', function(responseJson)
        {
            $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) 
            {
            $("#SALUTATION").val(item);
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: @Patik Bhatt Thanks(and +1) for answering, all three answers are solving my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because the request is asynchronous you need to make your second request after the first has completed. To do this put the function call in the callback of the first request, like this:

```
$.get(
    'MyServletName?action=cmbSALUTATION', 
    function(responseJson) {
        $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) { 
            $('<option>').text(item).appendTo($ul);
        });
        setValSALUTATION(); // Note: inside callback, so it will execute 
                            // once DOM is in the proper state
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks(and +1) for answering, all three answers are solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX means "Asynchronous Javascript" right, so the requests will be asynchronous meaning there will be no guarantee which one will be executed first. And for your case you require a synchronous operation (one call should follow after the other call, they are not independent of each other) so

try changing your code to this:

```
$.get('MyServletName?action=cmbSALUTATION', function(responseJson) 
{
   $.each(responseJson, function(index, item)
   { 
      $('<option>').text(item).appendTo($ul);
   });
   setValSALUTATION(); 
});
```

This will make sure that `setSalutation` is called only after the checkboxes are filled.

Comment: Thanks(and +1) for answering, all three answers are solving my problem.